# Почему казнь именно смертная?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, история

Как исторически сложилось, что казнь именно смертная? Возможно есть происхождение данного выражения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Казнь исторически была не только смертная, но и *гражданская* (позорящее наказание), а также *торговая* (публичное наказание кнутом). Об этих видах казни можно почитать напр. в одноимённых статьях Википедии. Соответственно, исторически в языке сохранилось уточнение "смертная". Сохранению способствует и благозвучие в  выражении с предлогом - "приговорить **к**..." ("к казни" менее удобно произносить, чем "к смертной").